# PHP GD memory usage very low VS very high

Tags: php, memory, gd

I have always understood that processing images using GD uses quite a lot memory.
On our productionservers however I found that the amount of memory used was a little bit too high, so I was diving into the code in order to see whether I could make some improvements at least.

While debugging I didn't get the results I was expecting so instead I created a small testscript that left me puzzled. I hope someone has got some new insights on this.

The script is just a plain script for testpurposes:

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit', '1M');

$src = __DIR__ . '/../images/image-15M.jpg';
$dest = __DIR__ . '/../images/output/resized-image-15M.jpg';

@unlink($dest);

list($srcWidth, $srcHeight, $srcType) = getImageSize($src);
$destImage = imageCreateTrueColor(1000, 1000);

$srcImage = imageCreateFromJpeg($src);

imageCopyResampled($destImage, $srcImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);
imageJpeg($destImage, $dest, 80);

if (file_exists($dest)) {
    die('Image created succesfully in output-directory');
}else{
    die('Failed creating image');
}
```

Now as you can see in this scenario I set the memory-limit to 1M. The script still runs fine.
On the production server the script runs out of memory as expected.

Now I've also tested this with a 500kB image. That one runs fine on my development environment, but on the production server it needed up to 16M to run.

My first conclusion was that there is something wrong on the production server. The main difference (there are a lot of differences actually including OS) that seemed relevant to me is the difference in GD:

Development:

```
'GD Version' => '2.2.5',
'FreeType Support' => true,
'FreeType Linkage' => 'with freetype',
'T1Lib Support' => true,
'GIF Read Support' => true,
'GIF Create Support' => true,
'JPEG Support' => true,
'PNG Support' => true,
'WBMP Support' => true,
'XPM Support' => true,
'XBM Support' => true,
'WebP Support' => true,
'JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support' => false,
```

Production:

```
'GD Version' => 'bundled (2.1.0 compatible)',
'FreeType Support' => true,
'FreeType Linkage' => 'with freetype',
'T1Lib Support' => true,
'GIF Read Support' => true,
'GIF Create Support' => true,
'JPEG Support' => true,
'PNG Support' => true,
'WBMP Support' => true,
'XPM Support' => false,
'XBM Support' => true,
'WebP Support' => false,
'JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support' => false,
```

Would the bundled version of GD make such a difference?

Then I realised that it is weird that my development script seems to be able to process a 16M image using only 1M of memory. I think that may be possible with efficient memory usage, but I'm not sure if that is how GD works.
Is there something wrong in my testcase?

I have tested the value of `ini_get('memory_limit')` after setting it and it says 1M, so that seems to be right.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes ok, but would that make such a big difference in memory usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer myself. I already found this bugreport, but I had not read the last comment well enough: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71093

The difference in memory consumption is because the bundled version of GD uses the memory allocated to PHP, while the OS version of GD uses it's own memory.

I still find this interresting though in that I could lower the memory_limit of PHP a lot.

Comment: Which OS btw...?

Comment: Centos and FreeBSD